# Shell script spools to a file but creates a zero byte file when ran by crontab

Tags: shell, sh, cron, sqlplus

I have a shell script that runs a SQLplus query and spools it to a file. The SQL query takes about 30 seconds to run within the script then will send it to a output.txt file. When I manually run the script from the Unix prompt, everything works fine (the output is sent to the output.txt file) but when the same shell script is automatically ran from a cron job I set up, It creates a zero byte (output.txt) file with no contents. Does anyone have any ideas why this works find manually but not when crontab kicks it off?

UPDATE:

I looked at my local mail file and saw the follow error:

```
/home/tuser01/mon.sh[21]: /bin/sqlplus:  not found
```

Here is my sqlconnect in the script:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus userid/password << Eossql
```

Any Ideas why I do not get "not found" when I manually run it but when it runs from the crontab it can't find that location?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because $PATH is different. The redirect to `output.txt` happens before the shell finds out it can't exec the command.

Cron may be sending you local mail with the error output.

Comment: Thanks, I did find the error in my local mail. I updated my initial question with the error I am getting. Do you know why I am getting that 'not found' error only when it runs from the cron?

Comment: The ORACLE_HOME variable is obviously not set. You are apparently setting ORACLE_HOME only in interactive shells or only in bash shells.  Set any environment variables you need in the crontab.

Comment: If you look at the code you see that you are trying to call `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus` and what it does complain not to find is `/bin/sqlplus` which tells us that the cronjob does not know a value of the ORACLE_HOME environment variable